# How can I apply a function to each element of a array column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset were a column in with an ARRAY of OBJECTs like this:

```
ID   TAGS
1    {"tags": [{"tag": "a"}, {"tag": "b"}]}
2    {"tags": [{"tag": "c"}, {"tag": "d"}]}
```

I want to extract the `tag` field of each element of the array, so the end result would be:

```
ID   TAGS
1    ["a","b"]
2    ["c","d"]
```

Assuming the following table `t1`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS (
      select 1 as ID , PARSE_JSON('{"tags": [{"tag":"a"}, {"tag":"b"}]}') AS PAYLOAD
    UNION ALL
    select 2, PARSE_JSON('{"tags": [{"tag":"c"}, {"tag":"d"}]}')

);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pure SQL approach would be to combine [LATERAL FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) and [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) like this:

```
with t2 as (
    select ID, t2.value:tag as tag
    from t1, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => payload:tags) t2
)
select t2.id, ARRAY_AGG(t2.tag) as tags from t2
group by ID 
order by ID ASC;
```

t2 itself will become:

```
ID  TAG
1   "a"
1   "b"
2   "c"
2   "d"
```

and after the `GROUP BY ID` it becomes:

```
ID  TAGS
1   [    "a",    "b"  ]
2   [    "c",    "d"  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to create a javascript function and use the [javascript .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply a function to each element of the array:

```
create or replace function extract_tags(a array)
  returns array
  language javascript
  strict
  as '

  return A.map(function(d) {return d.tag});
  ';

SELECT ID, EXTRACT_TAGS(PAYLOAD:tags) AS tags from t1;
```

this gives the desired result:

```
ID  TAGS
1   [    "a",    "b"  ]
2   [    "c",    "d"  ]
```

Comment: To make things more flexible, you could also return a specified key (instead of hard-coding `tag`). The signature would look like this: `extract(a array, k string)`, and you would just need to return `d[k]` instead of `d.tag`.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since this question has been asked, but I hope this could help anyone else who runs into this.
After running into the same issue ourselves, we wrote some UDFs to enable us to do these transformations quickly.

Using them, we can perform your query as:

```SQL
SELECT
  ID,
  tranform_array('x.tag', TAGS:TAGS) AS TAGS
FROM t1
```

Here is the repo with the functions, hope this could help.
https://github.com/OrrDermer/Snowflake-Semistructured-Functions