# How can I convert a JSON list of dicts to a list of strings in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table which contains an `id` column and a `favorite_books` column. The `favorite_books` column contains a list of dictionaries in JSON. Each dictionary has a `title` and a `ISBN` attribute:

```
ID | favorite_books
--------------------
42 | [{"title": "LotR", "ISBN": "9780261102354"}, {"title": "HP1", "ISBN": "9780545582889"}]
13 | [{"title": "Faust", "ISBN": "9780192835956"}]
```

My real case is more complicated, but the part that is missing is to select only the titles. So the result should be:

```
ID | favorite_books
--------------------
42 | ["LotR", "HP1"]
13 | ["Faust"]
```

I saw [Querying Semi-Structured Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html), but I'm still not sure how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply a function to each element of a array column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173623/how-can-i-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-array-column)

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [an existing answer for a similar data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173623/how-can-i-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-array-column), you can try it this way (using a CTE, exploding the array, then grouping it back into a new array based on the ID):

```sql
with elements as (
    select ID, elements.value:title as title
    from table_name, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => favorite_books) elements
)
select elements.ID, ARRAY_AGG(elements.title) as favorite_books from elements
group by ID;
```

Or via a javascript UDF that's more straight-forward (just transforms the array):

```sql
create or replace function extract_titles(A array)
  returns array
  language javascript
  strict
  as
  $$
    return A.map(function(d) {return d.title});
  $$
;

select ID, EXTRACT_TITLES(favorite_books) as favorite_books from table_name;
```