# how can I pass another parameter to javascript map() function

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to create generalized function from the solution given in the following link [array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173623/how-can-i-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-array-column/63394446?noredirect=1#comment112097299_63394446)

Say for example, my array looks like below

```
ID   TAGS
1    {"tags": [{"tag1": "a"}, {"tag1": "b"}, {"tag2":"123"}, {"tag2":"345"}]}
2    {"tags": [{"tag1": "c"}, {"tag1": "d"}, {"tag2":"789"}, {"tag2":"678"}]}
```

From the javascript UDF provided in the above link is working fine. However I wanted to use that as generalized one like getting values of tag1 and tag2 by passing them as input parameter. Please find below the UDF which is working fine to get the tag1/tag2 by calling them directly.

```
create or replace function extract_tags(a array)
returns array
language javascript
strict
as '
return A.map(function(d) {return d.tag1});
';
SELECT ID, EXTRACT_TAGS(PAYLOAD:tags) AS tags from t1; -- This will give the result for tag1.
```

I don't want to recreate the same function for getting the tag2 value's. Instead wanted to pass the KEY as parameter and get the desired result. Any help on this is much appreciated.. something like below.. sorry if the below code is inappropriate.. I'm new to java and snowflake.

```
create or replace function extract_tags(a array, b varchar)
returns array
language javascript
strict
as '
return A.map(function(d) {return d.{B}}); //Calling the second parameter to get the appropriate values
';

 SELECT ID, EXTRACT_TAGS(PAYLOAD:tags, 'tag1') AS tags from t1; --To get the tag1 values
 SELECT ID, EXTRACT_TAGS(PAYLOAD:tags, 'tag2') AS tags from t1; --Using the same function to get tag2 values
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I guess the map function should be `return d[B]`.

Comment: Thanks mate @Pipetus.. this worked

Answer (score 1):

In `return A.map(function(d) {return d.{B}});` the map function should be `return d[B]` instead.

(*copying @Pipetus answer in a comment to an answer, so this question can find closure as answered*)