# How to map object/json array in Snowflake SQL / DBT Macro?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

| id | some_attribute | json_array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "abc" | [ { attr: 'apple'}, { attr: 'banana' } ] |

How to get the get rid of `attr` in `json_array` so that the table results into something like table below?

| id | some_attribute | string_array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "abc" | [ 'apple', 'banana' ] |

Use case is during the cleaning stage of the data to make further processing and analysis simpler in later stages of the pipeline.

Thx for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply a function to each element of a array column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173623/how-can-i-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-array-column)

Comment: Thx @tconbeer, yes, I think that goes into the same direction as proposed below by Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to create a JavaScript UDF. For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ARRAY_JSON_VALUES("a" ARRAY, "attr" STRING) 
RETURNS ARRAY 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT IMMUTABLE
AS 
$$ 
  return a.map(e => e[attr]);
$$
```

then

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 1 id, 'abc' as some_attribute, [{ 'attr': 'apple'}, { 'attr': 'banana' } ] as json_array
)
SELECT 
  id
, some_attribute
, ARRAY_JSON_VALUES(json_array,'attr') as string_array
FROM
  data
```

again returns

```
ID|SOME_ATTRIBUTE|STRING_ARRAY      |
--+--------------+------------------+
 1|abc           |["apple","banana"]|
```

Comment: Thx Paul! This seems to be me the better approach because we're working normalization of bigger JSON documents and using the first approach with table flatten in SQL will make things quite complex.

The UDF approach seems neat and the UDF is easily re-usable. 

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to [`FLATTEN`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) the json array, then construct the string array from the values.

For example

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 1 id, 'abc' as some_attribute
, [{ 'attr': 'apple'}, { 'attr': 'banana' } ] as json_array
)
SELECT 
  id
, some_attribute
, ARRAY_AGG(value:attr::string) WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY index) as string_array
FROM
  data
, TABLE(FLATTEN(input => json_array))
GROUP BY
  id
, some_attribute
```

which returns

```
ID|SOME_ATTRIBUTE|STRING_ARRAY      |
--+--------------+------------------+
 1|abc           |["apple","banana"]|
```